# Abrir PDF base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um PDF em bytes e o converte para `ToBase64String` e envia astravés de um `JSON` para que o javascript possa abrir, porém no chrome ele não consegue ler esse arquivo e apresentar o PDF

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   $.post('/RelatoriosGerais/GerarPDF/', { CategoriaRelatorio: 1 }, function (data) {
                if (data.status = true) {

                    let Pdf = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.arrayByte;
                    window.open(Pdf, '_blank');
}
```

sendo que `data.arrayByte` é o base 64 que é retornado via JSON

OBS: Firefox funciona

Comment: Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas creio que data uri scheme tenha limite, que varia entre navegadores, neste caso me parece que Blob poderia ser melhor, porque o limite é maior, ooutra saida seria simplesmente gravar em arquivos reais.

Answer (score -1):

Penso que pode estar faltando a definição do tipo de arquivo a ser renderizado.... algo parecido com isso...

data:[][;base64],

Dê uma conferida no Data_URL do Mozilla...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

E também na RFC relacionada...
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397

T+

Comment: A definição esta correta `'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.arrayByte;`.